# Strip a date and time in R so you have each numerical component

Tags: r, date

I currently have dates stored as a factor in this format: `"01_03_2018 08-30-09"`

I am looking to strip each component out as a numeric value (in R code).

so the date above would be

```
day = 1
month = 3
year = 2018
hour = 8
minutes = 30
seconds = 9
```

Note: All these values need to be in numerical format.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, you can use `as.POSIXct` or `strptime` convert the date time into standard format

```
datetime <- as.POSIXct("01_03_2018 08-30-09", format = "%d_%m_%Y %H-%M-%S")
```

now we can use `format` and get respective components.

```
day <- as.integer(format(datetime, "%d"))
month <- as.integer(format(datetime, "%m"))
year <- as.integer(format(datetime, "%Y"))
hour <- as.integer(format(datetime, "%H"))
minute <- as.integer(format(datetime, "%M"))
second <- as.integer(format(datetime, "%S"))
```

Read `?strptime` for format options.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the variable with `dmy_hms()` from the `lubridate` package can produce what you want. The plus side of these functions from the package is quoting from [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/ymd)

> These functions recognize arbitrary non-digit separators as well as no separator. As long as the order of formats is correct, these functions will parse dates correctly even when the input vectors contain differently formatted dates.

```r
library(lubridate)

x <- "01_03_2018 08-30-09"

# dmy_hms specifies the order as day, month, year, hour, minute, second 

y <- dmy_hms(x) 
day(y)
# 1
month(y)
#3
year(y)
#2018
hour(y)
#8
minute(y)
#30
second(y)
#9
```

You can coerce them to the type of your liking then on. You might want to check the default type using `typeof()` though, if it already is in the type you want by default.

Answer (score 3):

If we convert to `POSIXlt` with `strptime`, all of these info can be extracted

```
lst1<- unclass(strptime(str1, format = "%d_%m_%Y %H-%M-%S"))
lst1$year <- lst1$year + 1900
lst1[c("mday", "mon", "year", "hour", "min", "sec")]
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "01_03_2018 08-30-09"
```

Answer (score 2):

To not use external library, you can do:

```
dat="01_03_2018 08-30-09"
tmp=gsub(" ","_",dat)
tmp=gsub("-","_",tmp)
vect=as.numeric(strsplit(tmp,"_")[[1]])
```

`gsub()` performs some substitutions to have only underscore as separator, and thus `strplit()` cut the string. Finally, it is converted to numerical values with `as.numeric()`.

The vector `vect` contains the final data.